# Multi select dynamic list using wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress please help me to create multi select dynamic list using wordpress.  please help me if there is any plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you want check boxes on Search form. It will be helpful.

> This plugin provides a Search Widget similar to the default WordPress
>   one but with the abilty of adding category select lists to restrict
>   the search query to only those categories.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/ab-categories-search-widget/

Answer (score 0):

Actually i have created one group of image in list form like filpkart,myntra,......etc those people just replace images and corresponding  name like in wordpress is that possible without any entering backend can we change the list